# cant make my makefile work

Tags: c++, makefile

Folder structure of project:

```
|--particle-system
|   |-- bin
|   |   |-- .o files
|   |-- docs
|   |   |-- design.md
|   |   `-- TO_DO
|   |-- Makefile
|   |-- src
|   |   |-- .cpp files + .h files
|   `-- test
```

I need to put all my .o files generated into the bin folder. Also cleanup should remove all .o files and the /bin folder.

My makefile:

```
# particle-system Makefile

EXE = particlesystem
OBJ_DIR = bin

CFLAGS = -g
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -g -std=c++0x
LDFLAGS = -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf -lSDL2_mixer -lSDL2_gfx -lm


 # c++ source files of the project
CXXFILES = $(shell find src -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.cpp')
CXXOBJ = $(CXXFILES:.cpp=.o)

ifdef V
MUTE =
VTAG = -v
else
MUTE = @
endif

all: $(EXE)
    # build successful

$(EXE): $(CXXOBJ)
    $(MUTE)$(CXX) $(CXXOBJ) -o $(EXE) $(LDFLAGS)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: src/%.cpp
    $(MUTE)$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $< -c -o $@


$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: src/%.c
    $(MUTE)$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $< -c -o $@

run: all
    $(MUTE)./$(EXE)

clean:
    # Cleaning...
    -$(MUTE)rm -f $(EXE) $(OBJECTS)
```

I dont know why this makefile isn't working. Please tell whats wrong here.

Comment: The reason why `clean` isn't removing your object files is because they're called `$(CXXOBJ)`, not `$(OBJECTS)`.

Comment: Also, you haven't defined `BUILD` anywhere.

Comment: The makefile isn't building anything. When I enter make, it just displays '#build successful' and stops. I dont even get why its displaying a comment.

Comment: Yeah, BUILD was just leftover from prev changes. My bad, removed it

Comment: The only reason it would do nothing and print the comment is if you've got a file called `particlesystem` already.

Comment: I dont have one. I have one called ParticleSystem.cpp but its different case.

Comment: Are all of the commands muted?

Comment: Yes , all commands are muted

Comment: Unmute them then, because otherwise you've no idea what's happening. It could be executing some of the commands.

Comment: Unmuting it didn't work as no other reply is provided by make. What should I try next?

Comment: I've added an answer with everything I can see that is wrong.

Comment: As others have pointed out, you will only see `# build successful"`, if the _particlesystem_ file is created. Try `ls` or `make run`. It really should be there.

And the line is no comment. Makefile comments have the '#' at the very beginning of the line. It is a _recipe_ to make goal _all_ out of '$(EXE)', so it is displayed only when '$(EXE)' exists.

Finally, if you want your object files in bin/, don't forget to create it first and use

    `CXXOBJS = $(patsubst src/%.cpp,bin/%.o,$(CXXFILES))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line will cause the `.o` files to be created in the same directory as the source files:

```
CXXOBJ = $(CXXFILES:.cpp=.o)
```

Consequently, these lines have no effect, because there are no `.o` files in `$(OBJ_DIR):`

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: src/%.cpp
    $(MUTE)$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $< -c -o $@

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: src/%.c
    $(MUTE)$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $< -c -o $@
```

Also, `$(INCLUDE)` isn't defined.

In this line, `$(OBJECTS)` isn't defined:

```
-$(MUTE)rm -f $(EXE) $(OBJECTS)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing this all out. Removing these errors helped me run the makefile.